# Netgear GS724TPv2 tagging a single port with multiple VLAN tags

Tags: networking, vlan, netgear-switch

In summary, I have a [Netgear GS724TPv2](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/gs724tpv2) switch that has a support PC attached to port 1. I have a Trunk line coming into the switch via port 23 (T) which sits across VLAN 131, 132, 133. Currently I have port 1 untagged "U" on VLAN 131, 132 and 133 (all VLANS sit across the same subnet range). However, I noticed it seems that I can only set 1 PVID at a time therefore my support PC can only speak to one VLAN at a time.

Does anyone know of a way that I can get port 1 tagging the PC traffic to VLAN 131, 132 and 133 at one time and then each VLAN traffic can respond to the PC without using  multiple NICs and switch ports going between switch and the Support PC?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're asking, but: an Ethernet frame can only contain one VLAN tag (excluding Q-in-Q and MAC-in-MAC scenario's, which do not apply here). So the only way to get traffic to multiple VLANs is by sending out multiple packets, or multicast packets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however I noticed it seems that I can only set 1 PVID at a time

Yes, because the purpose of the PVID is to act as the 'default' VLAN ID when the switch *doesn't know* which VLAN an incoming packet is supposed to go in – and it has no way of knowing that **because** the packets coming from your computer are untagged.

In other words, you just cannot have multiple untagged VLANs on the same port, because **tags are literally what carries the VLAN information needed for this to work.**

Normal usage would be either a) have all VLANs tagged on that port (the PVID remains unused) or b) have all VLANs tagged except one, and set the PVID to that one untagged VLAN.

(The switch does not keep track of which IP subnets correspond to which VLANs, and really, if your support PC specifically needs direct Ethernet connectivity to each VLAN, then chances are that your tools generate the kind of traffic that the switch couldn't map this way *anyway*.)

> without using multiple NICs and switch ports going between switch and the Support PC.

If you specifically need the computer to be *directly* attached to multiple VLANs on the same port, then it must generate (and understand) VLAN-tagged packets.

On Windows, you can achieve this using a Hyper-V "vSwitch" – it lets you create multiple virtual Ethernet interfaces, each corresponding to a specific VLAN tag, all associated with the same physical interface. (No, you don't need any VMs for this – these virtual interfaces can be created directly on the host OS.)

This is unfortunately not available through the Hyper-V GUI; you can create the "External" Virtual Switch through GUI but you'll need to add the VLANs through PowerShell:

```
Add-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -Name VLAN2 -SwitchName "External" -Passthru | Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -Access -VlanId 2
```

Earlier (before Hyper-V), many "server grade" Ethernet NICs also used to provide this ability at the driver level for Windows. (Linux or BSD already have virtual VLAN interfaces as a built-in feature.)

It's also possible that you don't really need direct Ethernet-level connectivity, but only IP connectivity, in which case you could stick a dedicated VLAN-capable router between the PC and the switch. (This task is almost always the job of a router anyway.)